# Windows Phone 8 Pivot Control background transparent / translucent

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How can I make a pivot control header not opaque so that the image from a scroll viewer slides the text of each pivot item?  I can make it a solid color and I can drop the transparency (so it seems) but I can't see the image underneath.

[image]

Here is what happens now.  I want the image to appear under it, not on top.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are talking about panorama page. a panorama page will help you do the stuff which you are looking for. read more about panorama page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941104%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

hope this helps.

Comment: No i meant pivot control  I want it customized so that the header is transparent and the image appears to slide under when scrolling.  I updated my question with an image.